# Cakephp master password

Tags: php, cakephp

In my CakePHP project I am asked to set a master password for users. So admin can login with any username of CakePHP and that master password.

In my mind I am getting this:

1. Either add a condition in somwhere in CakePHP login controller by validating any fixed password, if that comes, auto login user without checking the password or
2. if I am logged in as admin, I would like to create a page like `xyz.com/LoginAsAnyUser.php`
   where I can select a user from a combo box, and by selecting one I login to that user.

If you can provide a full code working code, with instructions about how to integrate this will very helpful for me.

Comment: A master password is bad for security, so go with 2 ('user switching'). Seaching turned up [one way](http://www.dereuromark.de/2012/12/15/user-switch-for-cakephp-apps/) somebody has implemented this.

Comment: #2 is what I always do. Authenticate the administrator using your normal security methods, once that is done you can allow that admin to switch to other accounts. Assuming your users are ok with admins doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not an expert in Cake, but i think this can be a very easy task. Can't you just create some method in controller that will populate the session with users username? I think you can just copy some of your code from login controller when you are setting some basic session and create a very specific one regarding your needs.

So basically going with option `2.)`

Comment: This is correct, you can use (from the controller) `$this->Auth->login(current($this->User->read($userId)))` and will be logged in as the user.

Comment: I want to create a button somewhere and when i will click on it let suppose UserId should set to 1 and user 1 will logged in now.  How to do like that?